# Regex to find last token on a string

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I was wondering if there is a way having this

```
var string = "foo::bar"
```

To get the last part of the string: `"bar"` using just regex.

I was trying to do look-aheads but couldn't master them enough to do this.

--

UPDATE

Perhaps some examples will make the question clearer.

```
var st1 = "foo::bar::0"
match should be 0

var st2 = "foo::bar::0-3aab"
match should be 0-3aab

var st3 = "foo"
no match should be found
```

Comment: as a separator, I want to have everything after the last '::' section, could be that after the '::' I have any other type of symbol, number, etc.

Comment: Can the last token contain `:`? If so, can it be `foo:::bar`, and how will you handle it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
/::(?!.*::)(.*)$/
```

The result will then be in the capture.

Another approach:

```
/^.*::(.*)$/
```

This should work because the `.*` matches greedily, so the `::` will match the *last* occurence of that string.

Comment: And if you have trailing whitespace, or may or may not have trailing whitespace, try `"\\w+\\s*$" instead.

Comment: This will not work for my examples, at it will match "bar::0" in the first example.

Comment: This won't work—`*` is greedy, and so will, for instance, match `bar::0-3aab` in `foo::bar::0-3aab`.

Comment: @Antal S-Z: You're right that it wouldn't work for the updated examples, but the reason you gave for *why* it wouldn't work is not right. It has nothing to do with the greediness. Using a lazy match `.*?` would also fail. I've updated my answer wiith a hopefully working version.

Comment: @Antal S-Z: Mentioning greediness gave me the idea for the alternative approach, so thanks for that. :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply,

```
/::(.+)$/
```

You can't use lookaheads unless you know exactly how long a string you're trying to match. Fortunately, this isn't an issue, because you're only looking at the end of the string `$`.

Comment: This will not work for my examples, at it will match "bar::0" in the first example.

Comment: This won't work—`+` is greedy, and so will, for instance, match `bar::0-3aab` in `foo::bar::0-3aab`.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use regular expressions for this (although you certainly can); I'd split the string on `::`, since that's conceptually what you want to do.

```
function lastToken(str) {
  var xs = str.split('::');
  return xs.length > 1 ? xs.pop() : null;
}
```

If you really want just a regular expression, you can use `/::((?:[^:]|:(?!:))*)$/`.  First, it matches a literal `::`.  Then, we use parentheses to put the desired thing in capturing group 1.  The desired thing is one or more copies of a `(?:...)`-bracketed string; this bracketing groups without capturing.  We then look for either `[^:]`, a non-colon character, or `:(?!:)`, a colon followed by a non-colon.  The `(?!...)` is a negative lookahead, which matches only if the next token *doesn't* match the contained pattern.  Since JavaScript doesn't support negative lookbehinds, I can't see a good way to avoid capturing the `::` as well, but you can wrap this in a function:

```
function lastTokenRegex(str) {
  var m = str.match(/::((?:[^:]|:(?!:))*)$/);
  return m && m[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var string2 = string.replace(/.*::/, "");
```

though perhaps `string` isn't the best choice of name for your string?